# How to get last modified timestamp of a partition in a bigquery table

Tags: google-bigquery

there is a way to get the last modified timestamp information of a partition in a bigquery table, using legacy sql `__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__` written here [list-partition](https://medium.com/@sureshdsk/google-bigquery-list-all-partitions-in-a-partitioned-table-cb00582a7e28),

```
SELECT 
project_id, dataset_id, table_id, partition_id, TIMESTAMP(creation_time/1000) AS creation_time
FROM [PROJECT_ID:DATASET_ID.TABLE_ID$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

But is there any way to get the same information using standard sql ?

tried to look at documentation about last modified time of partition in, both biquery client libraries, or in bigquery table documentation, but found none.

Comment: We plan to support partitions in [Information Schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro) so it can be queried through Standard Sql, but there is no ETA yet. For now it's only available in Legacy Sql.

Comment: @HuaZhang Are there any updates with respect to this?

Comment: Yes, it's now available: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#partitions_view

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery now offers [PARTITIONS VIEW](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#partitions_view) in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. The following code snippet can be used to list the partition specific update time:

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways you can get the information that you need

## Method 1: Using the `__TABLES__` metatable

The `__TABLES__` meta-table holds metadata about all tables in a dataset. And includes `last_modified_time` so you can determine when a table was last altered.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.sec_quarterly_financials.__TABLES__`
```

```
+----------------------+--------------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+------+
|      project_id      |        dataset_id        |   table_id    | creation_time | last_modified_time | row_count | size_bytes  | type |
+----------------------+--------------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+------+
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | calculation   | 1506951904786 |      1549897716323 |  12962167 |  1947409375 |    1 |
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | dimension     | 1506951963976 |      1549897966591 |   9375745 |  1347314982 |    1 |
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | measure_tag   | 1506952136026 |      1549898363265 |  18828446 |  3981179622 |    1 |
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | numbers       | 1506952752355 |      1549901192304 | 154567677 | 32759645886 |    1 |
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | presentation  | 1506952317542 |      1549900563489 | 108014012 | 15931119512 |    1 |
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | quick_summary | 1507817754713 |      1557588404913 |  68980952 | 13692158813 |    1 |
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | rendering     | 1506952854835 |      1549898767985 |  10089112 |  2395006363 |    1 |
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | sic_codes     | 1556128864207 |      1556128895225 |       444 |       20242 |    1 |
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | submission    | 1506953160779 |      1549897880524 |    209050 |    64383798 |    1 |
| bigquery-public-data | sec_quarterly_financials | txt           | 1506953237777 |      1549898391758 |  14254950 | 11635805575 |    1 |
+----------------------+--------------------------+---------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+------+
```

## Method 2: _PARTITIONTIME pseudocolumn

In Standard SQL, you can use the [_PARTITIONTIME pseudocolumn](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#the_partitiontime_pseudo_column) to inspect the date partitions on a table.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT MAX(_PARTITIONTIME) AS pt
FROM `bigquery-public-data.sec_quarterly_financials.numbers`
```

```
+-------------------------+
|           pt            |
+-------------------------+
| 2018-03-31 00:00:00 UTC |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: The answer doesn't address the specific metadata that the OP asked for, namely "last modified timestamp".